# Error when read or write a image to disk with servlet

Tags: java, vraptor

I created a Servlet to write and read images in an out-of-context location

When reading or writing an image to disk, the following error sometimes occurs:

The application continues to run normally even with the mentioned error ...

```
br.com.caelum.vraptor.InterceptionException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: APR error: -730054
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.controller.DefaultControllerNotFoundHandler.couldntFind(DefaultControllerNotFoundHandler.java:62)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.controller.DefaultControllerNotFoundHandler$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.couldntFind(Unknown Source)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.RequestHandlerObserver.handle(RequestHandlerObserver.java:96)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor338.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112)
at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: APR error: -730054
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:389)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:414)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
at br.com.eclesia2.kernell.servlets.ServletImageUrl.doGet(ServletImageUrl.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.controller.DefaultControllerNotFoundHandler.couldntFind(DefaultControllerNotFoundHandler.java:60)
... 34 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: APR error: -730054
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:292)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:245)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:214)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:175)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:41)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:350)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:84)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:257)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:492)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:384)
... 48 more
```

The JavaScript View

```
var url = $('#url').val();
if(url != null && url.length > 0) {
    $('#photo').attr('src', '<c:url value="/imageUrl?url=' + url + '"/>');
}
```

The Servlet

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    String url = request.getParameter("url");
    String mime = context.getMimeType(url);

    if(mime == null) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return;
    }

    response.setContentType(mime);
    File file = new File(url);
    if(!file.exists()) {
        return;
    }
    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    while((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>servletImageUrl</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>br.com.eclesia2.kernell.servlets.ServletImageUrl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>servletImageUrl</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/imageUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I use Java7, Tomcat 8 and VRaptor Framework. 
Why do these errors occur?